# Is it possible to use event file descriptor in combination with interrupt-driven input?

Tags: c, linux, io, system-calls

Here is the smallest possible example (error checking and signal safety are overlooked intentionally):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/eventfd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void reader(int a)
{
  printf("hello!\n");
  wait(NULL);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGIO, reader);
  int efd = eventfd(0, EFD_NONBLOCK);
  fcntl(efd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
  int flags;
  flags= fcntl(efd, F_GETFL);
  fcntl(efd, F_SETFL, flags | O_ASYNC);

  pid_t p = fork();
  if (p)
  {
    for(;;)
      pause();
  }
  else 
  {
    uint64_t buff = 1;
    if (write(efd, &buff, sizeof(buff)) == -1)
      printf("write error\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
}
```

This code should generate SIGIO in parent, after child writes to event file descriptor, but it does not. I've even tried to remove EFD_NONBLOCK from eventfd system call and I've got the same behaviour. So here goes couple of questions.

Is this a correct way of handling interrupt-driven I/O?

Can interrupt-driven I/O be used in combination with event file descriptors and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eventfd` file descriptor doesn't support `O_ASYNC` flag.

It seems that [man open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) describes all *current* implementors of O_ASYNC functionality:

> This feature is available only for terminals, pseudoterminals, sockets, and (since Linux 2.6) pipes and FIFOs.

Generally, if `O_ASYNC` flag is not supported by concrete file, it is silently ignored. One may check whether the flag is *successfully* set by followed F_GETFL:

```
// Try to set the flag
int flags;
flags= fcntl(efd, F_GETFL);
fcntl(efd, F_SETFL, flags | O_ASYNC);
// Check whether the flag is set
int new_flags = fcntl(efd, F_GETFL);
if(!(new_flags & O_ASYNC)) {
    // Failed to set the flag.
}
```

---

There was suggestions for `fcntl` to return error, if one want to set O_ASYNC flag which is not supported by particular file. [This mailing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fa.linux.kernel/2tDzW2dmono) is one of them. But according to current implementation of  kernel's function [setfl](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/fcntl.c#L32) them has been rejected:

```
if (((arg ^ filp->f_flags) & FASYNC) && filp->f_op->fasync)
```

(`FASYNC` is a synonim for O_ASYNC, `->fasync` callback, if exists, implements changing of the flag for concrete file).

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for some kind of report why it cannot work but couldn't find anything. It is very confusing when system call fails silently. I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: F_SETFL mode `fcntl` silently ignores some flags. Probably, the same decision has been choosen for `O_ASYNC` flag when it is set for inappropriate file. I have updated my answer with additional details and the way for detect, whether the flag has been successfully set or nor.

Answer (score 0):

the file descriptor returned by a call to `eventfd()` has nothing to do with generating a signal when the contents are changed via a call to `write()`.

If you want the parent to wakeup each time the file descriptor, an 8 byte value. is written to, then have the parent use `select()` where the input variable contains the file descriptor returned from the call to`eventfd()`.

The linux man page for `eventfd()` contains an example of how to use the `eventfd()` function.

the linux man page for `select()` contains an example of how to use the `select()` function.

Comment: I don't want to use select, poll, epoll etc. API. The question clearly states interrupt-driven I/O (https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Interrupt-Input.html#Interrupt-Input) which results in a signal being delivered. I know how to use it with select but it doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: the question clearly states you want to use the file descriptor returned from `eventfd()` to produce signals.   That will not happen.

Comment: But it is possible to get a signal when working with FIFOs and PIPEs, so I was wondering if anybody knows a workaround.